# In Professor Layton vs. Phoenix Wright what is responsible for the car accident?

Tags: professor-layton, phoenix-wright

The game starts with a car accident taking place in the middle of nowhere, probably within the walking distance from London. It is heavily implied to have been caused by witches magic making the statues alive. Facts corraborate that story - the car ends up at the top of the tree, police inspector (as unskilled at puzzles as he may be) has no explanation how it could have been done.

However...
(major game ending spoiler)

> magic does not exist and is the result of slightly futuristic technology in place and hypnosis. That however is set up only for the region Labyrynthia was in, possibly an island

With that in mind, what is the true story behind the accident? Did I miss an explanation somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although considered non-canon, an explanation is given in the postgame downloadable episodes, specifically the second one ("London").

The statues in the park were actually prototype robots created by Labrelum Inc. using "the very latest ultra-advanced technology." Labrelum had bought that land and planted the robots to prevent Accidenti from escaping the Great Witch's clutches. The land and robots had since been given back to the public, as Labrelum no longer needed them.